# What do you call the wooden bridge-like structures that make up a harbor?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

I’m referring to this:

[image: a marina dock in Port of Seattle with several boats moored on either side]

image: Harbor Island Marina in [Port of Seattle](https://www.portseattle.org/maritime/harbor-island-marina) (probable source: portseatlle.org)

I added a red arrow.

Example sentence:

> Boats lined both sides of the [. . .], bobbing quietly under the blue
>   sky.

Comment: That's a [pier](https://www.google.de/search?q=pier&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=vrcnVYjHGYfbaMTCgNgL&ved=0CDsQsAQ&biw=1027&bih=988).

Comment: Probably *piers*, or *walkways*. In Norfolk, home of the Norfolk Broads, and many hundreds of miles of river bank, there is a local word *staithe*. It is of believed Viking origin and exists at other places in Eastern England which were influenced by medieval Danish.

Comment: In the photo, it is specifically a floating [marina dock](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22floating+dock%22+marina&biw=1047&bih=484&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=I_knVc2LGsW_sAWOhoHIBw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=%22marina+dock%22).

Comment: I've most commonly heard it called a "dock" (here in Minnesota, where there are many such structures).

Comment: If, like the one in the picture, it floats, then it's a 'pontoon'. The vertical pieces which are inserted into the bed of the river are 'pilings'. The machine which inserts them is called a '[pile driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pile_driver)'. If it doesn't float then it's a 'pier' (large) or a 'jetty' (small). If you don't know or care whether it floats or not then the generic term is a 'mooring'. Collectively a bunch of moorings form a 'marina', one or more of which can often be found in a 'harbour'. In a larger version for ships it's a 'dock' or 'quay'. (British English)

Comment: In British English a "dock" is the body of **water** used by ships for loading and unloading cargo, not the structures surrounding or enclosing it. Water used for mooring non-commercial boats (as in the picture) is often called a "marina" not a "dock". A "dry dock" is a dock where the water can be pumped out for the purpose of repairing a ship's hull, etc. The plural "docks" can also be used to refer to the entire working area of both water and land in port, e.g. "Liverpool docks" is the physical structures, and the "Port of Liverpool"  is the legal entity or company that operates the docks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accurate British English term for an oblong deck from shore out into a lake where you tie your rowing boat](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76076/accurate-british-english-term-for-an-oblong-deck-from-shore-out-into-a-lake-wher)

Comment: @AE: That's a good answer. Or it would be, except that it's not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: @Ilmari, thank you, I'm glad you find it useful. I posted it as a comment rather than an answer because I didn't have the time or inclination to track down the necessary references. If you want to find them and post an answer based on my comment then go right ahead.

Comment: Aleph zero is right, 'dock' has a couple of different senses in BrEng, including the body of water and (I'd argue) the quay as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It’s a *pier* or a *dock* or a *wharf*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_(maritime)#American_English):

> In American English, a dock is technically synonymous with pier or wharf—any human-made structure in the water intended for people to be on.

The structure shown is clearly a human-made structure in the water intended for people to be on. Therefore, it is a dock in American English.  Whether it is also a pier or wharf may vary depending on what part of the world you live in.  Here it would also be called a pier.

Yes, it’s floating.  But it’s still a floating pier or floating dock.

Comment: It's not a pier, dock, wharf or quay (source: OED). Piers and quays are solid structures, not floating, and quay is mostly use for structures that are "on land" rather than jutting into the water; a dock is an area of water; wharves are "on land".

Comment: @DavidRicherby - you sure that there is no definition of 'dock' that includes something like a "structure extending alongshore or out from the shore into a body of water, to which boats may be moored"?

Comment: @Brendan The OED doesn't include any definition along those lines. The closest would be sense 5a, "A range of dock-basins (sense 4a [the area of water]) together with the adjoining wharfs, warehouses and offices."

Comment: @DavidRicherby [In American English, a dock is technically synonymous with pier or wharf—any human-made structure in the water intended for people to be on.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_(maritime)#American_English)  You will note that the picture is of a human-made structure in the water intended for people to be on. It is therefore a *dock* in American English.

Comment: @tchrist I'm surprised that the OED doesn't mention that. Do you also have sources for the other terms you quote being used in US English? I'd happily upvote a revised answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, this is a [floating dock](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=floating+pier) or [floating pier](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=floating+pier), but that doesn’t change it from being a dock or a pier. You should be able to see plenty of examples of this usage for these things, plus pictures, in those links. I’d prefer not to link directly to commercial sites if possible.

Comment: @DavidRicherby [This is a picture of exactly the same thing: “small motor boat moored near floating wooden pier”](http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-images-small-motor-boat-near-floating-wooden-pier-moored-image35867999).

Comment: I can confirm that the object in the picture can be called a "floating dock" in US English.

Comment: Pier and dock jump to mind. The OED is just a dictionary. It  doesn't determine usage. Wikipedia has it right and my experience with AmE is in accord (English of the American South and Southwest mixed with some of New England). The one thing it's not is a jetty, and imho it's too small for a wharf.

Comment: @δοῦλος I'd have called it a _pier_ myself, but it is a _jetty_ in the UK.

Comment: For completeness sake this answer should include "jetty". Even if we already have a separate answer for jetty.

Comment: @δοῦλος: I can confirm that that is definitely a jetty. Over here we have jetties large enough to house a customs & immigration building and have smaller piers connected to it

Comment: @slebetman I understand the sentiment, but I don't see the need for it, plus I wouldn't feel right about doing that. There does not need to be just one answer that is all things to all people. Andrew's answer offers something of value. I never knew these words were used so differently to either side of the Atlantic. Plus I like his pictures. ;-)

Comment: @slebetman I've only ever heard "jetty" used to refer to those piles of boulders that extend from a beach out into the ocean

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Fortunately, that is no longer true. You've just heard "jetty" used to refer to structures referred by the OP here :)

Comment: @slebetman that was also before I read the answer directly below this one, too.

Comment: @David Richerby If a _dock_ is a body of water, was [Otis Redding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCmUhYSr-e4&gl=BE) really Jesus taking a rest when he was "sittin' on the _dock_ of the bay"?

Comment: @oerkelens As has been established, British and American usage differ on the word "dock". I was not previously aware of this and the OED, my primary reference, doesn't mention it at all.

Comment: @pazzo "The OED is just a dictionary. It doesn't determine usage." Of course. But the OED does try to *document* usage extremely thoroughly. Usually, if the OED doesn't mention a usage, it means that that usage wasn't common when that entry of the dictionary was last revised.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know and respect the OED. But it's impossible that it can have every single usage of every possible word, especially oral usages, since they're not documented. The best source for contemporary usages are native speakers.

Comment: @pazzo Agreed. But the source of data you mention can be associated with very unrepresentative sampling techniques. OED does have a rejection policy for over-niche usages.

Comment: It is not a wharf or pier.

Answer (score 15):

One word is ***jetty***.

> A landing stage or small pier at which boats can dock or be moored:
>   *Ben jumped ashore and tied the rowboat up to the small wooden jetty*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jetty)

It appears that this is a British-English usage of the word and American English uses different words for various marine structures — or uses the same words in different ways. Despite that,
Google images for *jetty* include the sort of thing illustrated in the question:

[image: Jetty]
<sup>[xlibber](http://www.flickr.com/people/56844661@N00) via [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jetty_%284676078969%29.jpg)</sup>

...and some rather larger structures:

[image: Jetty]
<sup>Luke Roberts via [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Largs_bay_jetty.jpg)</sup>

Comment: By the disparate answers thus far, it seems there 's little agreement; it seems there's room for a whole nother question here (if not already answered):  what ARE the differences between a dock, wharf, quay, and jetty? Are they regional? I, for example, would never call the OP's picture a jetty, quay or pier; it is clearly a dock (which serves as a moorage). The "rather larger structure" is a pier. Piers are usually at the ocean, and have to be high above the water to accommodate tides.

Comment: Docks float on the water, though they are often mounted to posts with rings, allowing them to rise and fall with water levels. The ramp in OP's photo is not firmly connected to the dock, so it too can accommodate changing water levels.

Comment: @Brian: docks only need to float on the water where there are tides.

Comment: I always thought a jetty was simply a line of rocks sticking out in the water for waterbreaking purposes, not for getting off a boat. (but I see some definitions include the concept of pier).

Comment: I agree with @Mitch. I always thought of a jetty as being made of rocks, for the purpose of redirecting a current and protecting a shoreline. See this from [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/jetty): *A projection of stone, brick, wood, or other material (but generally formed of piles) ... serving as a protection against the encroachment or assault of the waves; ... a pier of stone ... projecting from the bank of a stream obliquely to its course, for the purpose of directing the current upon an obstruction to be removed ... or to deflect it from a bank.*

Comment: There may be a US-UK difference. The top picture is definitely what I would call a jetty (in the UK).

Comment: @AndrewLeach nice catch. yes, in AmE, a jetty is rocks or rubble. kids might play on it or maybe people fish, but a boat would not want to come close to it. A stone pier is an architected structure, designed and built for permanence, for larger ships to dock at. It would be solid (no pilings for water to rush around).

Comment: Yes, [trans-Atlantic difference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_(maritime)#American_English).

Comment: What I liked about this term was the etymology; jactare, jeter, to cast or throw. It brings to mind that jetties are used both for fishing (casting lines) and launching (casting off) watercraft... the same root as _jettison_.

Comment: @Peter Shor: A dock/pier also needs to float (maybe even more) if it's on a reservoir where the water level can change due to hydropower, irrigation, &c.  And I always associate 'wharf' with commercial cargo.

Comment: @PeterShor: So, docks on lakes _don't float?_ Or do you claim that if it's on a lake, it's not a dock?  How about the ones on rivers, where water level fluctuates, but not due to tides? Are you saying those aren't docks either?  I guess there really is a transatlantic disconnect on these terms.

Comment: @Brian: I'd say a dock is any structure where you dock a boat and then get off the boat onto the structure. If there are tides, or the water level changes, then they have to float. But if the water level is constant, they don't need to. Google [lake dock](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1116&bih=632&q=%22lake+dock%22&oq=%22lake+dock%22&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1269.4628.0.4877.13.12.1.0.0.0.99.779.12.12.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.64.img..1.12.724.6okB6GT_bQo).

Comment: @Brian: on the other hand, people in the U.S. use the phrases "swimming docks" and "fishing docks", which aren't used for boats. I wouldn't call anything raised significantly above the water a "dock" (that's a "pier"), but if you image Google "fishing dock", you see a number of things I'd call a "pier". So maybe the words really are synonymous in the U.S.

Comment: @Mitch - surely a line of rocks sticking out into the water for waterbreaking purposes is a groyne or a breakwater (depending on its angle the shore)? In British English, I've never heard such a thing called a jetty unless it was used for embarkation and/or disembarkation.

Comment: @francis that's my point, you are using BrE and I am using AmE

Comment: @Mitch - I was confused because (from what I have read) both "breakwater" and "groyne" (well spelled differently) are AmE terms for the same things as in BrE. Are the terms overlapping or is there a line drawn between them?

Comment: @FrancisDavey 'groyne' is unfamiliar to me. I suspect 'breakwater' is the same in both. This whole Q/A has taught me that jetty is different. In AmE, a jetty is not for em- or dis-barcation at all (so I think no overlap there) at least in my own idiolect. The connection (that infer) is they're both manmade things sticking out in the water.

Comment: @PeterShor - Actually, docks need to float when on rivers or lakes that can rise and fall seasonally.

Comment: I get the pretty much the same images for *jetty*, *pier* and *dock* on Google.it, if that helps :). Pontoon is quite a different story. Images of boats for some reason.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't know if google is taking AmE and BrE differences into account. Or maybe it is and you're seeing the BrE version.

Comment: @Mitch perhaps because I have set the language to English? Who knows.

Answer (score 14):

I'd usually refer to them as a "pontoon".

Jetty, dock, quay and pier all tend to be non floating.  The OP's original picture is a device that floats with the tide but is kept in place by the upright poles so the boats are always at the same level as the "artifical ground level" created by pontoon.

The floats under the decking are often referred to as pontoons (much like the pontoon on a sea plane) but the decking and floats combined are what I would call a Pontoon

Comment: Pontoon might be used on the floating dock but I'm not sure if you can call the whole structure pontoon.

Comment: Best answer IMO, when you say pier I think of a pier like Brighton pier, when you say dock I think of docks like the London docks, but when you say pontoon I think of this.

Comment: technically, the pontoon is the floating boats under the decking.

Comment: I believe @Oldcat is correct, in that the term "pontoon" strictly speaking refers to the floats, but it is fairly commonly used in the UK to refer to this sort of structure.

Comment: Yes, pontoon or floating dock. Not quay, jetty, wharf or pier.

Answer (score 6):

It is variously a pier, dock, wharf, jetty, or pontoon, depending on the local dialect and sophistication of the speaker.  Call it a "dock", and everyone will understand what you're talking about while only a few of them will yell at you for mis-using terminology.

English has an enormous and highly-detailed vocabulary regarding ships and their support facilities that developed back when travel by water was the best way to get around.  The distinctions have been fading in the past century or so, and many formerly-distinct terms are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 4):

"A pier is a raised structure, including bridge and building supports and walkways, typically supported by widely spread piles or pillars. The lighter structure of a pier allows tides and currents to flow almost unhindered, whereas the more solid foundations of a quay or the closely spaced piles of a wharf can act as a breakwater, and are consequently more liable to silting. Piers can range in size and complexity from a simple lightweight wooden structure to major structures extended over 1600 metres. In American English, pier may be synonymous with dock." "A jetty is a structure that projects from the land out into water. Often jetty refers to a pier, wharf, dock, breakwater."  from wikipedia. so its a jetty and a pier/dock. hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

The first word that came to mind for me was "pier." Several others have noted that "dock" and "wharf" are also appropriate, which is entirely true.

Answer (score -2):

The object in the original picture is, in British English, without doubt a 'pontoon'. If there is any doubt, confusion or conflicting suggestion of any merit, it will only be due to any variations between British and American English.

Comment: Not my downvote. Please provide support for your answer, otherwise you are only repeating somebody else's answer and expressing your personal viewpoint.

Comment: In the US a "pontoon" would most definitely be a floating object, but one that was only loosely moored, by ropes from an anchor, eg.

Comment: I suspect the distinction, in this case, comes down less to Br vs Am English, but rather to the level of sophistication of the speaker; to those not informed of proper nautical terminology, all of the words proposed are, for the most part, used interchangeably

Answer (score -2):

If pontoon referred to the whole structure there'd be no need for the expression *pontoon bridge*.  As someone who read far too much military history as a child, I can assure you that it does exist.

Comment: English isn't as regimented as some would imagine it to be. From AHDEL: _pontoon_ 
b. A floating structure that serves as a dock. >>  Explains the downvote (not mine; new people here need some rep points so that they can give comments).

Answer (score -3):

Boardwalk
- a path for pedestrians , typically made out of wood and running alongside the beach. 
Source: English Dictionary

Comment: You might want to consider putting a link to a dictionary site with this definition.