# A word for a wooden platform on the river bank used in the old times for fishing or laundry

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a small wooden platform on the river bank used in the old times for fishing or laundry (not for docking boats)?

[image]

Comment: You might be thinking of a [jetty](http://dictionary.com/browse/jetty).

Comment: That's what came to my mind too. Why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: I believe a jetty is a pile of rocks in a particular formation. The ones I've seen, anyway (I've seen a lot of them).

Comment: There is a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238522/what-do-you-call-the-wooden-bridge-like-structures-that-make-up-a-harbor) about wooden structures extended from the land into water.

Answer (score 3):

This is called a '**fishing platform**' if it is used for fishing, as it often is.

> Fishing platform, Kennington Park Lake, Thurrock

[Geograph](http://www.geograph.org.uk/photo/3220445)

[image]

Comment: and what if it's only used for laundry?

Comment: @Yevheniy8 I think it would then become the only 'laundry platform' in the world.

Comment: Where I'm from (a coastal area, with rivers) anything of this sort would be called a "dock", regardless of use.